# Why is string.replace in Python not working?

Tags: python

I have the following python string:

```
game="""+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   4   |   5   |   6   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   7   |   8   |   9   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
"""
```

This is considered a `str` still and I used the following to replace `"5"` with `"X"`:

```
game.replace("5","X")
```

Then I print the output and still get:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   4   |   5   |   6   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   7   |   8   |   9   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Python strings are immutable, `.replace` returns a *new* string.

Comment: `.replace` is not an in-place operation.  use `game = game.replace('5','X')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are printing the wrong string. You need to print game.replace('5','X') directly or use an intermediate variable.

Comment: Ah thank you you reminded me of something ill update this

Answer (score 2):

What you are probably doing is

```
game="sample string 5"
game.replace("5", "X")
```

This wont work because python strings are immutable and `.replace()` doesn't modify the original string, it returns a new one

To fix:

```
game = game.replace("5, "X")
```

A little word about what it means for Strings to be immutable in python - it simply means that they cannot change during the runtime of the program.

Comment: correct I forgot about this.